# It is possible background works for every 1 minutes in ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Hello firstly I am so sorry about my bad english level.

I have an application. 
Basically my application works for every 1 minutes use get method for getting some json data from server.
It is possible in android side and i created with foreground service.

But for xamarin.ios side how i can create?
actually my question is it is possible for in ios?

Comment: Can you show us how you did it successfully, and any attempt that is giving you trouble in Xamarin so far?

Comment: dear @gravity i don't understand u

Comment: You should probably look into BGTaskScheduler for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler However, i think the minimum interval between fetches is around 15 minutes and can't be lower.

Comment: @Cheesebaron thanks for answer. i will look documentation

Answer (score 0):

Before doing that , you can have a research with [backgrond tasks in iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks#creating-background-safe-tasks) .

The biggest change in iOS 7 with regard to background tasks is not how the tasks are implemented, but when they run.

Recall that pre-iOS 7, a task running in the background had 600 seconds to complete. One reason for this limit is that a task running in the background would keep the device awake for the duration of the task:

[image]

iOS 7 background processing is optimized for longer battery life. In iOS 7, backgrounding becomes opportunistic: instead of keeping the device awake, tasks respect when the device goes to sleep, and instead do their processing in chunks when the device wakes up to handle phone calls, notifications, incoming emails, and other common interruptions. The following diagram provides insight into how a task might be broken up:

[image]

Because the task run time is not longer continuous, tasks that perform network transfers must be handled differently in iOS 7. Developers are encouraged to use the NSURlSession API to handle network transfers. The next section is an overview of background transfers.

If you can keep the device not be killed , you can have a try with using [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers#the-systemthreadingtimer-class) class to use `Timer` to implement what your want:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    private static Timer timer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timerState = new TimerState { Counter = 0 };

        timer = new Timer(
            callback: new TimerCallback(TimerTask),
            state: timerState,
            dueTime: 1000,
            period: 2000);

        while (timerState.Counter <= 10)
        {
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        }

        timer.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}: done.");
    }

    private static void TimerTask(object timerState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}: starting a new callback.");
        var state = timerState as TimerState;
        Interlocked.Increment(ref state.Counter);
    }

    class TimerState
    {
        public int Counter;
    }
}
```

In addition , the first doc share the [Background Transfers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks#background-transfers) notes .***The backbone of background transfers in iOS 7 is the new NSURLSession API.***